# MySQL copy ip address from varchar column to integer in the same table

Tags: mysql

I want to copy the same "clean" IP number from a varchar(32) column into an integer one.

I tried this:

```
  UPDATE table SET ipnum = REPLACE(ip, '.', '');
```

But for some values I get different numbers than the original "clean" ones.

For sure I'm doing something wrong, but can't figure out what is it.

Example how it works now:

```
ip  varchar(32) numip int(11)
-----------------------------
41.220.68.241   2147483647
41.58.115.152   2147483647
41.220.68.13    412206813
```

I want the output to be this:

```
ip  varchar(32) numip int(11)
-----------------------------
41.220.68.241   4122068241  
41.58.115.152   4158115152
41.220.68.13    412206813
```

Comment: include some sample data, and expected output

Comment: Methods already exist for converting ip numbers to integers, this isn't one of them. what happens if you have `41.220.61.13` and `41.220.6.113` ?. Your 'incorrect numbers' look like integer overflow values.

Comment: Removing the "dots" to get an integer value is kind of odd. The numeric value of the result can exceed the maximum size of a 32-bit integer. Likely, the "different" numbers you are seeing are `2147483647` (or `4294967295`) the maximum values for 32-bit signed integer (unsigned integer). With a 64-bit integer `BIGINT` you wouldn't exceed the maximum value there. *but* **what are you trying to achieve?** The result of that conversion can't reliably be converted back into an IP address because it's ambiguous. Compare the results given e.g. `192.168.1.212` and `192.168.12.12`,

Comment: The BIGINT fixed the problem. Thanks! I do not need them converted back.

Comment: @gnollmarauder why convert them at all if different ip addresses are going to give the same numeric value? the correct way to do this is given in an answer below.

Comment: The "decimal dot" format of an IP address is a convenient way of expressing the value of four binary bytes. That's much more convenient than a string of 32 1s and 0s, or 8 hexadecimal digits. To convert those four bytes into decimal value... we take the first byte (as tinyint unsigned) multiply by 256*256*256 plus the second byte (as tinyint unsigned) times 256*256 plus... but there's a builtin function that does that for us. (And the resulting value does "fit" into a 32-bit unsigned integer `INT UNSIGNED`. Just removing the dots is, how to put this politely, ... **bizarre**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably use the built in functionality for this:

```
mysql> select INET_ATON('10.0.0.1');
+-----------------------+
| INET_ATON('10.0.0.1') |
+-----------------------+
|             167772161 |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

[12.15 Miscellaneous Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton)

> Given the dotted-quad representation of an IPv4 network address as a
>   string, returns an integer that represents the numeric value of the
>   address in network byte order (big endian). INET_ATON() returns NULL
>   if it does not understand its argument.

You can reverse the process with `INET_NTOA`, eg:

```
mysql> select INET_NTOA('167772161');
+------------------------+
| INET_NTOA('167772161') |
+------------------------+
| 10.0.0.1               |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This is the right way to convert "dotted decimal" string representation of IPv4 addresses into unique integer values. (**+1**). The OP approach "removing the dots to get an integer" is bizarre (to put it politely), If we weren't as polite, we'd more likely describe "removing the dots from an IP address to get an integer" as syphilitic idiocy. (It's a good thing we're polite, I guess.)

Comment: I believe the polite term is "syphilis-induced dementia". and i think we're all a bit surprised and impressed to learn that there is a built in mysql function for handling the already demented IPv4 notation.